# Rename https://example.com/index.html with page name

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I'm currently hosting my website on Hostinger and I have a little issue. Mmy URL is now like this: `https://example.com/home.html` and I would like to replace the `home.html` with the page name

Comment: What do you mean by "the page name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean `https://example.com/home` or `https://example.com/`, so I explain both:

1. `https://example.com/home`:
   To make it looks like this you just create a folder called "home". Then you put your `home.html` into this folder and rename it to `index.html`
2. `https://example.com/`:
   Just rename your `home.html` to `index.html`.

NOTE: Do this inside the `public_html` folder.

Comment: It was the first option, but when i created the home folder and rename the home.html into index.html, it looks like this : https://robinpaysage.fr/Accueil/index.html

Comment: You never need to include `index.html` in your links.  In fact you shouldn't.  `index.html` is the file name that is meant to power the URL ending in `/` (the directory URL).